# How can i give other array values keys the same as specified array?

Tags: php

after sorting the $at1 array , iwant the other arrays keys to be sorted as $at1 array !

```
<?php
$p1 = array (0=>'p1',1=>'p2',2=>'p3',3=>'p4',4=>'p5');
$at1 = array (0=>0, 1=>4, 2=>7, 3=>6, 4=>2);
$cbt1 = array(0=>5,1=>1,2=>2,3=>2,4=>1);
asort($at1);
?>
```

Comment: This is too minimal. How does at1 relate to the others? You could iterate over `$at1` and use its key to select the corresponding ones of the other arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like homework :)

```
$p1 = array (0=>'p1',1=>'p2',2=>'p3',3=>'p4',4=>'p5');
$at1 = array (0=>0, 1=>4, 2=>7, 3=>6, 4=>2);
$cbt1 = array(0=>5,1=>1,2=>2,3=>2,4=>1);
asort($at1);
$a_keys = array_keys($at1);
$p1 = repeat_order($a_keys, $p1);
$cbt1 = repeat_order($a_keys, $cbt1);

function repeat_order( $mask=array(), $haystack)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach ( $mask as $key ):
        if ( isset($haystack[$key]) ):
            $result[$key] = $haystack[$key];
            unset($haystack[$key]);
        endif;
    endforeach;
    
    // If the array to be sorted had more elements
    foreach ( $haystack as $k => $v ):
        $result[$k] = $v;
    endforeach;
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: var_dump($p1); //giving Null value not an array :(

Comment: See carefully your syntax 
I've got result as below

array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "p1"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "p5"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "p2"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "p4"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "p3"
}